# Solve $y^{2/3}+(y')^{2/3}=1$ other than the direct method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any way to solve

$$y^{2/3}+(y')^{2/3}=1$$

other than just solving for $y'$ and then integrate?

Comment: you can try solving using AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos^2 u + \sin^2 u = 1 \Rightarrow (\cos^3 u)^{2/3} + (\sin^3 u)^{2/3} = 1$

Let $y = \cos^3 u$ such that $y' = \sin^3 u$, if possible.

$y = \cos^3 u \Rightarrow\\
y' = -3 (\cos^2 u \sin u) u' \Rightarrow\\
-3 u'\cos^2 u \sin u = \sin^3 u \Rightarrow\\
3u' = -\tan^2 u \Rightarrow\\
\displaystyle \int -3 \cot^2 u\, du = x + c \Rightarrow\\
3 \displaystyle \int 1 - \csc^2 u\, dy = x + c \Rightarrow\\
3(u + \cot u) = x + c
$

Now, $y = \cos^3 u \Rightarrow u = \cos^{-1} y^{1/3} \Rightarrow \cot u = \dfrac{y^{1/3}}{\sqrt{1 - y^{2/3}}}$

Thus the solution is

$$\boxed{3\left( \cos^{-1} y^{1/3} + \dfrac{y^{1/3}}{\sqrt{1 - y^{2/3}}} \right) = x + c}$$

Comment: Hope I've made no mistakes in the steps. Solved it right here without trying it out on paper.

Comment: The $cos^-1$ (in the final solution) should be $sin^-1$ according to my solution by integration (I haven't checked with detail each step of yours, so I am not sure where you error is, i did check mine with Mathematica) but this is the method i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Trollkemada If $\sin^{-1}$ is correct, then so is $\cos^{-1}$.

Comment: You are right! Sorry then =D

Comment: @Trollkemada $\sin^{-1} x - \dfrac{\pi}{2} = \cos^{-1} x$, for example, so they differ only by a constant.